# Which tools (that are not plugins) can be used to create animation which can be manipulated at runtime?

Tags: javascript, animation

sorry this is probably not the best place to ask, but I am not sure where else I can go to ask about this.

Basically on a website, I want to be able to create a short animation which plays like a video when a user presses a button. However based on some initial settings that can vary I would like to play this animation in different ways. For example faster or slower, or manipulate an object in animation in a different way (say for example you can indicate direction where the ball will fly before animation starts...)

The main requirement is that it shouldnt be a plugin like flash (where I am pretty sure those things can be achieved) unless there is absolutely no other way.

Also, the video is not just a simple vector based graphics but a full blown 2d drawn animation.

Does anyone know a framework or JS library or something that would let me achieve this effect? Or maybe can point me in the right direction?

I have to admit as a .Net developer I am completely clueless about all things animation or video related

Comment: You'll want to look at the HTML5 [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), implemented by all modern browsers.

Comment: is the animation in a video file (e.g: avi, mp4, etc)

Comment: Hi, the animation doesnt exist yet. I am looking for the best way to approach this, so it can be any format that will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [transitions in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). They are convenient, easy-to-use.

If you are more like a mathematician, then the [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) tag was made by you, but pay attention: it is supported by HTML5 and you need a fallback logic.

If you are more like a designer, then you can create a gif file and display it.

As about videos, I believe you should not stream videos, they will eat up the user's memory.

Comment: Hi, if I understand correctly, canvas essentially means drawing in real time, using code, but what I am looking to do is split the video in several independent objects which can be moved independently from each other I.e. a car driving on a road, a passerby walking by and sun rolling above - all of these need to be able to be animated independently, so that I could change their individual speed, direction, or maybe even replace one object with a different one all during the playback, or rather before playback based on user input. Is it possible to do with canvas? (Or CSS transitions?)

Comment: This is also why a prerendered video is not going to cut it, that means gifs or video streaming essentially

Comment: @Tanuki, do not imagine the canvas element like the one a painter uses. Essentially it is an HTML tag called canvas, which is used for programmatic drawing. It is up to you to decide how the code which will draw is generated and when. You can program an animation anytime and then display that for users. Or you can program a real-time drawer. So, you did not really read the documents I have given you, unfortunately.

Comment: CSS transitions can be assigned to pseudo-classes or to classes. A javascript code can add or remove classes to and from tags, combining animation. So, naturally, you can do it with gifs if you want small-sized animations. Or you can do it with canvas, if you are mathematical and not necessarily a painter. It boils down to what suits you best, really.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation, it makes things much more clear to me now.